# aiml - last occurrence of a word

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, aiml

I'm trying to add some files to A.L.I.C.E. AIML chatbot (I'm currently using a Python interpreter for AIML v1.0.0). Right now I'm stuck in a problem: I'm using two wildcards on a pattern and the word TO to separate them. Now the point is that the first wildcard can also contain the word TO, so it leads me to an error:

```
<category>
    <pattern>SAY * TO *</pattern>
    <template>Ok, I will say "<star />" to "<star index="2" />"</template>
</category>
```

A normal conversation could be:

```
-Client: Say Hi to mom
-Bot: Ok, I will say "Hi" to "mom"
```

But this other conversation gets me an error:

```
-Client: Say I have to go shopping to mom
-Bot: Ok, I will say "I have" to "go shopping to mom"
```

(Note that the quotes in the bot's answers are absent, I just put them here so you can see exactly what I mean)
Right after writting this, I realized I could mark that TO with some flags to recognize it. I tried these patterns:

```
<pattern>SAY * "TO *</pattern>
<pattern>SAY * "TO" *</pattern>
<pattern>SAY * TO" *</pattern>
<pattern>SAY * -TO *</pattern>
<pattern>SAY * -TO- *</pattern>
<pattern>SAY * TO- *</pattern>
```

but none of them works, either the interpreter or the aiml itself cant recognize the characters.

Is there any way to match these wildcards properly? Any suggestions?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it didn't take me too long to find the XSPLITTER tag, so I had to fix it out like this

```
<category>
    <pattern>SAY * XSPLITTER TO *</pattern>
    <template>Ok, I will say <star/ > to <star index="2" /></template>
</category>
```

Now, the inputs have to be a bit weird:

```
-Client: say I have to go shopping xsplitter to mom
-Bot: Ok, I will say I have to go shopping to mom
```

I guess I'll need to filter the input so i can edit it to add the xsplitter myself, and also add the substitutions (me->you, he->she and so)